# Can't find a way to use pagination because url stays the same when going to "next" page

Tags: beautifulsoup

how do you figure out what the next url should be when url stays the same whenever you go to the next (button) page? Does it have something to do with the aspx?

```
import requests as re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = ("http://www.voltagepictures.com/titles.aspx")
page = re.get(url)
   
soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
wrap = soup.find_all('div', class_="title")
for det in wrap:
   tit= det.text.strip()   
   print(tit)
```

Comment: You're not really going to the next page. It seems more that you iterate over the titles of that single page.

Comment: hope that helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66186456/how-to-scrape-single-url-multi-pages-using-requests/66187126#66187126

Comment: Thanks Samsul, but I'm afraid your code is way to complicated for me :-) I am impressed though!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using selenium. It waits for the page to load, then you can do your scrape. Then find the 'Next' button and click it. You can then do the scraping on that page, etc...

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") # you can comment out this line to see the browser in action
url = "http://www.voltagepictures.com/titles.aspx"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
# driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# do your scraping here

# go to 'Next' page - copied xpath from inspect element
submit_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[34]/div/div[3]/input[1]')[0]
submit_button.click()
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan!